# Middleware not restricting the routes using laravel 5.4.6

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a problem dealing with middleware,

[image]

here is database user 
[image]

here is AdminMiddleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return redirect('/admin-login');
    }


}
```

Here is route code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {

Route::get('/dashboard', 'BackEnd\HomeController@getDashboard');
});
```

But when i login then it doesn't work and redirect to only login page, please guide me how to deal with middleware issue.

Comment: Why is your password in plain text and not bcrypted?

Comment: sorry that is for demo purpose for posting the question

Answer (score 1):

You want a group of admin-only routes, right?
You could instead use the `can` middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'BackEnd\HomeController@getDashboard');
});
```

which will check the authorization policy, which you can define in your `Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
Gate::define('admin', function (User $user) {
    return $user->admin == 1;
});
```

If the check fails, you will get an "Unauthorized" response.

If instead you want the redirect to the login page, you could insist on your custom middleware, it should just be

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin == 1)
```

[Adnan Mumtaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933470/3208258) is correct, the password should not be in plain text in the database, instead it should be encrypted (save instead the result of `bcrypt('12345')`).

Answer (score 0):

Your password is not in bycryted you should do

```
echo bycryp(12345) // paste this in db and then try again
```

I hope this  this works not tested

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
  if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
    return $next($request);
  } else {
    return redirect('/admin-login');
  }
}
```